# Differrent posts_per_page number of custom post type in different WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type 'portfolio' and different WP_Query for different custom post pages and purposes.

For portfolio page I want to select 12 posts_per_page of portfolio type.

For main page I want to select 8 posts_per_page of portfolio type.

For block Similar Works on Single work page I want to select 4 posts_per_page of portfolio type.

At the moment in all wp_query I have a var $posts_per_page for this number. But it doesn't work, because I added a function in functions.php for defining a default custom portfolio posts per page value. And it's 8. So now I have 8 posts per page in all queries. The reason I added this function was to make a pagination to work. That function:

```
function portfolio_posts_per_page( $query ) {
   if ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'portfolio' )  $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 8;
   return $query;
}
if ( !is_admin() ) add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'portfolio_posts_per_page' );
```

Should I just remove this function and change Blog posts per page var in admin panel of Wordpress to 1? Like it was before. Or is there another solution to this issue?

**UPDATE**

I was trying to change the function into this, but then wordpress doesn't work at all:

```
function portfolio_posts_per_page( $query ) {

if ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'portfolio' ) {

        if ( is_post_type_archive('portfolio') 
            $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 12;
        }
        elseif (is_front_page()) {
            $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 8;
        }
        elseif ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
            $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 4;
        }
        else {
            $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 4;
        }
}       
return $query;
}
```

Comment: What template page it's you are working ?

Comment: First is static Front-page template (custom template file - custom-main.php), second is archive-portfolio.php - custom post type archive, third is single-portfolio.php - single page template for custom post type portfolio.

Comment: It seems you have separate templates for each custom post type, am I right ?

Comment: If you have separate template files then use separate custom query for each template.

Comment: Queries are different with different posts_per_page variable inside. But after enabling pre_get_posts func they just don't work. I'd add all 3 queries in a couple of minutes soon.

Comment: Updated the answer with link, also check [this article](http://devotepress.com/wordpress-coding/when-to-use-pre_get_posts-in-wordpress) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each of your custom post types, the template files use a custom query; for example, if you have a custom template named `archive-portfolio` then use something like this in that file:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 8 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

This is just an example, same way, you use a different template file for another custom post type and use completely different arguments. For the main query on home page, you may set up  on `WordPress` `backend`. Read more on [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).

**Update:** Check [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700826/using-multiple-custom-post-in-the-same-page/17704020#17704020) for `pre_get_posts`.